# Trying to move an element created after document load into another element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on this website: https://nuebar.com/ and I've just installed an app by shopify the places their currency selector right at the very bottom of the site, and I'm trying to move it into a div class .CSPosition that's been placed in a list item next to the current currency selector in the header.

Doing this because none of my international customers are finding the selector at the bottom of the site and the one at the top of the site doesn't change checkout currency, so will be removing it once I can move the one at the bottom successfully.

I've written this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("locale-selectors__container").addEventListener("load", moveUp);
function moveUp () {
    "use strict";
    $(".locale-selectors__container").insertBefore(".CSPosition");
}
```

to try and move it once it's been loaded since it's being loaded by a third party but it's not working.

I've also tried:

```
$(".locale-selectors__container").load(function(){
    $(".locale-selectors__container").insertBefore(".CSPosition");
});
```

I've also tried doing it when everything has loaded:

```
$( window ).on(function(){
    $(".locale-selectors__container").insertBefore(".CSPosition");
});
```

Is it because of limitations with elements inserted by a third party of am I making stupid mistakes? Is there something wrong with my two methods?

Comment: Does `$(function() { $(".locale-selectors__container").insertBefore(".CSPosition"); });` make any difference?  Looking jQuery's info, maybe `$( window ).on(function(){` needs load? => `$( window ).on('load', function(){`

Comment: I've now got:

`window.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
     
        console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
        const source = document.querySelector('.locale-selectors__container');
const destination = document.querySelector('.CSPosition');
destination.append(source);
      });`

But I have 'null'showing where the five should be. I'm not super versed on javascript. I know that the app injects the currency selector after every single thing has loaded. So is there a way to have your solution load after absolutely every possible thing that could be loaded has?

Comment: @PaulT. I've added in a setTimeout for 10 seconds which gets this working. It's not ideal but because the selector is being injected by a third party It's I think the only way to circumvent any loads they've placed on their end...

Comment: try DOMContentLoaded https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event

Answer (score 1):

setTimeout example

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    waitForSource();    
});

function waitForSource(){
    setTimeout(function(){
        const source = document.querySelector('.locale-selectors__container');
        if (!source) {
            waitForSource();
        }else{
            const destination = document.querySelector('.CSPosition');
            destination.append(source);
        }
    }, 350); 
}
```

setInterval example

```
let checkSourceInterval = null;
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
    checkSourceInterval = setInterval(() => {
        const source = document.querySelector('.locale-selectors__container');
        if (!!source) {
            const destination = document.querySelector('.CSPosition');
            destination.append(source);
            clearInterval(checkSourceInterval);
        }
    }, 350);
});
```

Comment: both of these are a lot slicker than mine, setInterval though definitely has a slight edge on load speed, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
     
        console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
        const source = document.querySelector('.locale-selectors__container');
const destination = document.querySelector('.CSPosition');
destination.append(source);
      }, 5000);
```

The setTimeout was the only way to circumvent and document/window/DOM loads that the app has on their end.
Now onto styling.